# Json Swfit 3 привидение типов

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, swift3

Получаю Данные с БД

```
  let myJson=try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSArray
```

Вывожу их в консоль .ВСЕ окей .
но вот пытаюсь получать значение по ключу так сразу крашится

```
  print(myJson.value(forKey: "name") as! String)
```

Вот тип ошибки

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleObjectArrayI' (0x1085ccdb0) to 'NSString' (0x107bd8c60).
```

Comment: покажи JSON проблема может быть в нем

Comment: Сделал проблема была в приведении типа надо было в аррай оттуда в словарь а оттуда в стринг )Можешь сказать как из потока nsurlsession взять данные для передачи в Vieü

Comment: этого я не знаю,  но думаю тебе надо completionHandler   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1410330-datatask  или  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1407613-datatask

Comment: он есть из него надо и достать )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794701/how-to-get-data-to-return-from-nsurlsessiondatatask-in-swift   думаю это тебе поможет     completionHandler(data, response, error)